# Wordpress Categories, subcategories, loop

Tags: wordpress

I am using [this tutorial on Wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action). Following it, I understand that I need to change it to display 5 titles instead of one post, but my understanding is a bit limited. I also need help in displaying the post underneath the "featured" posts with their category and sub-categories.

Thanks!

Code for the FEATURED section thus far. I want the image to the left of the featured section to just be the first image from the most recent post regardless of it's category. I'm gonna use CSS to add the Title and what not on top of it.

```
    <!-- Featured SECTION -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-7 columns">
    <?php 
      $thumbnails = get_posts('numberposts=1');
      foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
          echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
          echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'front-large');
          echo '</a>';
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="large-5 columns latest">
   <h5 class="subheader">Featured</h5>
     <ul>
     <?php
     foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category ) {
     $the_query = new WP_Query('featured' . $category->category_nicename . '&showposts=5');
     while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
     ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php
     }
     ?>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div><!-- END Featured SECTION -->
```

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Can you post your code and how you want it to look like?

Comment: @msbodetti I added the top part that I coded. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin-> https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-post/

When you var_dump($post) you will see full information of the posts, which you have made feutured